# Split largest group by regex in python

Tags: python, regex

first of all, i'm new at stackoverflow, so if there is any mistake on my part, i apologize. I will try to not make those mistakes again.

So the problem is, i'm trying to use regex to split a sentence, or a corpus with the format as:

```
outside <X TYPE='X1'> inside <X TYPE='X2'> inside </X> <X TYPE='X3'> inside </X> </X> outside.
```

where outside and inside is just random words (unicode); `<X TYPE='X?'> </X>` is a full tag and there can be tags inside it.
The result which i want should be like this:

```
["outside", "<X TYPE='X1'> inside <X TYPE='X2'> inside </X> <X TYPE='X3'> inside </X> </X>", "outside"]
```

Which means i want to split the sentence by the largest tag (sorry for my english).

All my attempts to do this only result in splitting by the smallest tags (tags which are inside the largest tag).
Can anybody show me a way to accomplish this ?. Thank you very much.

Comment: Regex is not the best tool for nested XML tags. Have you considered using a proper XML parser instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, regex is probably not the best tool for the job, and you might get better and more reliable results with a proper XML parser library. However, for your case, the following seems to do the trick:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "outside <X TYPE='X1'> inside <X TYPE='X2'> inside </X> <X TYPE='X3'> inside </X> </X> outside."
>>> re.split(r"(<.+>)", text)
['outside ',
 "<X TYPE='X1'> inside <X TYPE='X2'> inside </X> <X TYPE='X3'> inside </X> </X>",
 ' outside.']
```

This will `re.split` by the largest string enclosed in `<...>` and also keep that part due to the capturing group `(...)`. Note, that this simply captures the text before and after the *first* and *last* tag respectively, but *not* necessarily the text outside of any tags!

```
>>> text2 = "outside <X> inside </X> outside, too? <X> inside again </X> outside."
>>> re.split(r"(<.+>)", text2)
['outside ',
 '<X> inside </X> outside, too? <X> inside again </X>',
 ' outside.']
```

If, instead, you want the individual tags, just change the `.+` to `.+?` to split by the smallest such groups.

```
>>> re.split(r"(<.+?>)", text)
['outside ', "<X TYPE='X1'>", ' inside ', "<X TYPE='X2'>", ' inside ', '</X>', ' ', "<X TYPE='X3'>", ' inside ', '</X>', ' ', '</X>', ' outside.']
```

You could then use this to find the text outside of any tags using a stack or a simple tag counter:

```
parts = re.split(r"(<.+?>)", text2)
for part in parts:
    if part.startswith("<"):
        tags += -1 if part.startswith("</") else +1
    elif tags == 0:
        print(part)
```

Comment: It might be worth to capture the tag name to make sure to match up to a corresponding closing tag. Even then it would capture a single group in `<x>A</x>B<x>C</x>`. That said your answer might be sufficient for OP's needs.

Comment: @Aaron True, but assuming the XML is well-formed this should not be necessary.

Comment: The answer is so simple i have never thought of it. I will also look into a XML parser libraby. Thank you very much !

Comment: @Fuih Please note the part I just added in the middle. It really depends on what you see as "outside" whether it's that simple or you should use a proper XML lib.

Comment: @tobias_k uh yeah, I hadn't considered that. Still can be a problem with multiple non-nested tags (either `<a>...</a>outside<a>...</a>` or `<a>...</a>outside<b>...</b>`, only the second of which could be avoided by using backreference) but I think you've sufficiently warned OP